# Custom Build Tool by file-type

Tags: delphi, build, delphi-ide

can I associate a custom build tool automatically for all files of a certain type (i.e. I want to run my custom build tool for all files with *.mjs extension).

In the Delphi Doc I only found a way to manually associate a single file: [Adding a Custom Build Tool](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Adding_a_Custom_Build_Tool)

I am using Delphi XE3

Answer (score 0):

the answer is: you cannot do this with a custom build tool

a workaround is to use a pre-build event which searches the whole source tree for related files (e.g. ending in *.mjs) and then do the processing.

another disadvantage of custom build tools is that you cannot properly [report errors back to the IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146646/how-do-i-report-error-messages-to-the-ide-from-a-custom-build-tool)

so the conclusion is to avoid custom build tools and use pre-build events instead