# How do I report error messages to the IDE from a custom build tool?

Tags: delphi, build, delphi-xe3, delphi-ide

I am using a [custom build tool](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Build_Tools) in Delphi XE3.

This executes as expected, but when my custom build tool fails for some reason, it will return a non-zero exit code and Delphi will just report that the build has failed. The build tool will write to stdout and stderr in case of any errors, but those do not show up in the *Messages* window:

- the *Build* tab just shows **Failed** (after brcc32 is run)
- in the *Output* tab I can see that

  - the target BuildVersionResource is run, then the target PreBuildEvent is run
  - then my custom pre-build event is run (here I can also see what it writes to stdout) - this also succeeds
  - and then I only see: **Build FAILED** - but I see nothing related to the custom build tool

How can I fix this, or where can I find detailed help for custom build tools? The Delphi IDE help is really very basic.

Here's the full Output tab text as reference:

```
Build started 19/03/2015 14:57:44.
__________________________________________________
Project "C:\Xxx\Xxx.dproj" (Build target(s)):
Target BuildVersionResource:
    c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\bin\cgrc.exe -c65001 Xxx.vrc -foXxx.res 
    CodeGear Resource Compiler/Binder
    Version 1.2.2 Copyright (c) 2008-2012 Embarcadero Technologies Inc.

    Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0

    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


    Deleting file "Xxx.vrc".
Build FAILED.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:00.82
```

Comment: I use pre build, or post build actions, and they do capture standard out/err.

Comment: yes, but with the pre-build event I had problems: i.e. I generate some *.pas files out of other source-files - and when one of the source files were open in the Delphi Editor the IDE did not recognize that the file had been changed - this is better with the custom build events.

Comment: I also switched back to the pre-build event - without proper error reporting the custom build events are useless.